# how to set a passed function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am creating a new object variable and passing an object as an argument:

```
var obj = new test({
    first : $('#fname').val(),
    last : $('#lname').val(),
    fn : function() {
        alert(this.first + " " + this.last);
    }
});
```

This is the called function when creating the above variable:

```
var test = function(obj) {
    this.fn = function() {
        alert("No custom function was made.");
    }

    this.first = obj.first;
    this.last = obj.last;
    if(obj.fn)
        this.fn = obj.fn(); //I also tried it without the '()' after 'obj.fn'
};
```

The first and last variables are fine, but I cannot figure out how to get the custom function that is passed to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you tried removing the '()' after 'obj.fn'... seems to work when I do that.  Here's the link to verify: http://jsfiddle.net/TD93x/3/

Comment: mhmm wow ok idk why but it worked. i already tried that a bunch of times..... -_- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

it worked for me

```
var test = function(obj) {
    this.fn = function() {
        alert("No custom function was made.");
    }

    this.first = obj.first;
    this.last = obj.last;
    if(obj.fn)
        this.fn = obj.fn;
};
```

Comment: mhmm wow ok idk why but it worked. i already tried that a bunch of times..... -_- thanks!